# AttributeError: __exit__ error even though email is sent

Tags: python

I am trying to only send the email when excel file is non empty (there is data beyond the header), and do nothing otherwise.
This is probably something stupid I am overlooking, but the query below is throwing an `AttributeError: __exit__` error. I thought the `with` statement should have taken care of that (`f.close()`).

Would you mind checking what's wrong please? Thank you!
Please note that regardless of the error, the email is actually sent, but the message in the `else` statement is not printed.

```
with xlrd.open_workbook('name.xlsx').sheet_by_index(0) as f:
    if len(f.readlines()) > 1:  
        insert script to send email # If excel is not empty, send output via Email
    else:
        print('No new data') # dont send email
```

Comment: __exit__ is called when an object is being removed, do you have full traceback and see which object is complaining?

Comment: File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Python-Scheduler/Self-Serviced.py", line 49, in <module>
    with xlrd.open_workbook(name +'.xlsx').sheet_by_index(0) as f:
AttributeError: __exit__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f` in this case is the sheet, not the workbook. Also, if you want `close` to be called you would have to wrap it in `contextlib.closing()`; `with` only works with context managers.

You could try something like:

```
import contextlib
with contextlib.closing(xlrd.open_workbook('name.xlsx')) as workbook:
  f = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
  if f.nrows > 0:
    pass # has rows
  else:
    pass # has no rows
```

But I'm pretty sure `workbook`s don't maintain any resources. I don't think they even have a `close` method.

Comment: the workbook should handle the context manager, but the sheet doesn't, and `xlrd.open_workbook('name.xlsx').sheet_by_index(0)` returns a Sheet object

Comment: One comment, how the keyword __with__ works is basically calling magic function \_\_enter\_\_ and \_\_exit\_\_ inside an object. Here it seems the \_\_exit\_\_ is not defined for sheet. See http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm for ref.

Comment: Just checked the xlrd source and you don't have to worry about closing the file, the file is closed inside the __open_workbook__ functions.

Comment: I got "AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'close'" and the email was sent even though it was just the header. After removing the contextlib argument it took care of the error, and I adjusted to nrows>1. Thanks!